# QSettings rewriting the .ini file, so not able to restore the values

Tags: qt, qsettings

When I am using below code on Linux SLES 11 machine the .ini file is recreating for some reason so that I am not able to restore my settings.

Same code working fine on Windows machine.

Prb: I want to have recently opened file list on start up window, so that user can select quickly.

```
void Window::saveRecentFileList()
{
    QSettings settings(m_settingsPath, QSettings::NativeFormat);
    settings.setValue("recentFiles/list", QVariant(m_recentFilesList));
}

void Window::restoreRecentFileList()
{
    QSettings settings(m_settingsPath, QSettings::NativeFormat);
    m_recentFilesList = settings.value("recentFiles/list").toStringList();
}
```

Comment: Maybe `restoreRecentFileList` called after `saveRecentFileList`?

Comment: @vahancho   no in constructor i am calling restoreRecentFileList & in destructor i am calling saveRecentFileList

Comment: Your code is fine. May be the problem is in ini-file or some other code. Try to write a simple test app.

Comment: other code is fine actually, i print m_recentFilesList and checked its working as expected, but I have observed that, some how the file is getting recreated and hence loosing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `QSettings::IniFormat` instead of `QSettings::NativeFormat`. On Windows, you should be using `QSettings::IniFormat` anyways with a specific ini file location. Linux uses ini files as its native format for settings storage, but the [QSettings documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#accessing-ini-and-plist-files-directly) suggests that:

> On all platforms, if you want to read an INI file directly, you can
>   use the QSettings constructor that takes a file name as first argument
>   and pass QSettings::IniFormat as second argument.